# Android app not supported on some devices even though they are "supported" in the Play Console under supported devices

Tags: android, google-play-console, mobile-devices

I recently started testing my app to my friends in an internal test. 80% of them could download the app with no problem at all but some of them get the message that their device isn't supported. I checked the supported devices in the Play Console and even though, for example, the Samsung Galaxy A50 is supported according to Google Play Console, the person with that phone get's the message that his device isn't supported.

I tried to change SDK versions but this didn't change a thing. Since my app is a communication app it first graded is as an app where you need to have an age of 13+ and since some of them didn't register their age i tried to change this. This all didn't change a thing.

I tried searching on the internet but I just couldn't figure out why.

my gradle is as follow:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zjef.*********"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.zjef.**********'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I only got these permissions, but the problem occured even before that:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.yourpackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.yourpackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```